# How to disable react-native-element's checkbox touchable opacity?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

Actually, I am using react-native-element design language. When I used to implement checkbox than it behave like touchable opacity that I dont want.

```
<CheckBox
  containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", borderWidth: 0 }}
  center
  size={14}
  title="vegetarian"
  textStyle={{
    fontSize: theme.FONT_SIZE_X_SMALL,
    fontWeight: theme.FONT_WEIGHT_LIGHT
  }}
  checkedColor="red"
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
/>;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass a `Component` prop (which is `TouchableOpacity` by default), with `TouchableWithoutFeedback` for instance as value.

```
<CheckBox
  Component={TouchableWithoutFeedback}
  containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", borderWidth: 0 }}
  center
  size={14}
  title="vegetarian"
  textStyle={{
    fontSize: theme.FONT_SIZE_X_SMALL,
    fontWeight: theme.FONT_WEIGHT_LIGHT
  }}
  checkedColor="red"
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
/>;
```

Comment: I added above, but is how error can't find variable: TouchableWithoutFeeback

Comment: You also need to import this component in top of your file : import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'

Comment: yep, its working I found out another way like activeOpacity={1}

Answer (score 3):

we can do it by anotherway `activeOpacity={1}` as prop like below.

```
<CheckBox
  activeOpacity={1}
  containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", borderWidth: 0 }}
  center
  size={14}
  title="vegetarian"
  textStyle={{
    fontSize: theme.FONT_SIZE_X_SMALL,
    fontWeight: theme.FONT_WEIGHT_LIGHT
  }}
  checkedColor="red"
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
/>
```

Comment: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#props there is no such property `activeOpacity`

Comment: This component uses a <TouchableOpacity /> component (https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#component) which uses a activeOpacity property. This answer is fine.

Comment: Such hack does not work with typecript. But if we ignore typescript simple property `disabled` works perfectly fine

Comment: Thank you - It worked for my `Button`. For some odd reason, their docs don't list it as a prop for all the components it works for. (e.g., `ButtonGroup` has it listed in the docs, but not `Button`. https://reactnativeelements.com/search?q=activeopacity )

Answer (score 2):

This is not mentioned in the documentation, but there is a available props *"disabled"*

```
    <CheckBox
          disabled={true}
          title={l.name}
          checked={!!indexCheckBox.includes(i)}
          checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
          uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
          checkedColor="#6cc49a"
          uncheckedColor="#6cc49a"
          onPress={() => onPressCheckBox(i)}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

For Button, i just used below one it works for me.
let me know if it didn't.

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";

<Button
      TouchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
      title="Next"
      raised
      activeOpacity={1}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                      }}>
                      <CheckBox
                        disabled={false}
                        boxType={'square'}
                        value={this.isChecked(item._id)}
                        onCheckColor={COLORS.SWDarkBlue}
                        onFillColor={COLORS.SWLightBlue}
                        tintColors={{
                          true: COLORS.SWDarkBlue,
                          false: '#4445',
                        }}
                        onTintColor={COLORS.SWDarkBlue}
                        onValueChange={value =>
                          this.onToggleCheckBox(item._id)
                        }
                        style={checkBoxContainer}
                      />
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: example like this this would help for you if you have one TouchableOpacity with checkbox and navigation code

Comment: You can edit your own answer rather than commenting on it.